# Matlab: Unable to store information into array

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, graph

Im trying to store values from radialspeed (a function from the phased array toolbox) into an array, but im getting errors:

```
Conversion to cell from double is not possible.

Error in modelCar (line 40)
Cell(1,T)= Rspeed;
```

^^Error Message

```
Cell = cell(1,12)

for T = 1:11

[POS,v] = step(H,T);
Rspeed = radialspeed(POS,v,[25; 25; 70],[0; 0; 0]);
typecast(Rspeed,'uint16');
Cell(1,T)= Rspeed;
%%Rspeed = Vel.Radspeed(:,T);


disp(Rspeed);


end
```

^^^Excerpt of the code im using.

Another question any tips to plot a graph continuously while in the loop, the draw now function doesn't seem to work

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `Cell` as a variable since `cell` is reserved keyword in MATLAB. Though using `Cell` will pose no problems, but a simple typing mistake can inject errors into your code. You may use `myCell, R_cell` etc.

By writing, `Cell(1,T)= Rspeed` you are trying to assign `Rspeed` of type `double` to a `cell` datatype. You should write `Cell{1,T}=Rspeed` or `Cell{T}=Rspeed`. You can also visualize your output for each iteration as follows:

Replace `disp(Rspeed)` by:

```
hold on;scatter(T,Rspeed,'ro');
pause(0.001);
```

Comment: Thanks but I am getting  an empty plot.

Comment: @user3340930 oh ya... you should get points, but anyway, `scatter` is the better command to use here. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks, it only captured the last point onto the plot, just like what plotnow did when i tried

Answer (score 0):

1st question: `Cell(1,T)` will return a cell so you need to change your code to `Cell{T}= Rspeed;`.

2nd question: recall `plot` is a possible solution if speed is not a main concern.